# My PHP file does not execute the code in the else condition

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code to serve my mobile app to insert some data into the database, however when it enters the else condition, it cannot send the mail to myself. I am quite sure my mail function is okay to send as I have moved the code to another PHP file to have a test, so why it does not work here? So I try if it can create a txt file, but no file occurs after the execution also.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log") or die('Error! ' . mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT `Type` FROM `Log` WHERE `TechID` = '".$TechID."' ORDER BY LogTime DESC LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysql_query($query) or die('Error! ' . mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
      $count = $row1['COUNT(*)'];
      if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0)
          {
         while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
             {
            if($row2['Type']!="Checkin")
                {
               $count = $count+1;
               $timezone = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
               if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
                  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
               $Time = date('Y/m/d H:i');
               mysql_query("INSERT INTO Log (LogID, TechID, ClientID, SiteID, LogTime, Type)
                    VALUES(".$count.", '".$TechID."', ".$ClientID.", ".$SiteID.", '".$Time."', 'Checkin')");
            }
                else
                {
                 mail('me@gmail.com', 'test mail', 'Just a test');
                 $content = "First folder"; 
                 $fp = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/Me/checking.txt","wb"); 
                 fwrite($fp,$content); 
                 fclose($fp);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Is the `else` block ever actually entered?

Comment: Do you really want 1 email for every row that is not type 'Checkin' ?

Comment: Verify your database if you really dont have a record with Type='Checkin', you can update one record and set its Type to 'Checkin' to see if you reach the else block

Comment: actually, it will only have one row, because I have used Limit 1 in the query, ya, I am quite sure the else block is being executed, because I have my last record in database is checkin, and then I have tried to choose the option checkin in my mobile app, and no more record is adding into the database. Actually I have another part of code is checkout to serve the checkout option of the app, and it runs correctly, so I am quite sure the insert function is okay, that is why I have no idea why scripts in the else does not execute at all

Comment: `I am quite sure the else block is being executed` so the problem could be the mail() function configurated badly, and permission for frwite() ? Enable all error_log and see what happens

Comment: there is why I want to ask, since no more record is add, but in my php file, the only way where no recrod is inserted is the else part here, and the mail function is okay, as I have copied it and tried in another simple php file, but I dont know about the fwrite, as this php file is used to serve the app, so it is not opening in the browser, therefore I cannot print out something to help debugging it, so I am in trouble recently

Comment: to make it clear, I have moved the fwrite out of the block. The record can be inserted, but no file can be created, so probably, my file does not have the permission to create the file. Or if php file is not executed in a browser, then it cannot send mail of create file?

Answer (score 0):

Do a var_dump() of `$row2['Type']`:

```
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
           var_dump($row2['Type']);
           if($row2['Type']!="Checkin"){
```

and see what the Type key really contains, even a white space make fail that test (or you can try with `if(trim($row2['Type']) != "Checkin"){`)

Comment: I have tried your way, but still the file cannot be created and mail is not sent to the mail server also. The only reason should be it does not enter the else node, but I have no idea why